# Trigonometry Problems in Two Dimension

Tags: trigonometry

The angle between the shaft and the blade of a hockey stick is 120 degrees. The shaft is 1.5m long and the blade is 25 cm long. Determine an exact expression for the straight line distance from the top of the shaft to the tip of the blade.

I solved this problem, and the answer I got was 1.639 meters. 
I am having trouble, writing the answer as a exact expression. Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Use the Law of Cosines. (Draw a picture to see why and how.)

If you get stuck with that approach, or you're not sure that what you've done is correct, please feel free to leave a comment, and I will try to help you out some more.

Answer (score 0):

RA = 180-120
   = 60
SideAngleSide(SAS), ∴ cosine law can be applied.

1.5m converts into 150cm

c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ac(cosθ)

```
= 150^2 + 25^2 - 2(150)(25)(cos60)

= 22500 + 225 - 7500(0.5)

= 22500 + 225 - 3750

= 18975
```

If the answer calls for an exact expression, then the final answer would be the 2nd last step of the problem, which is c = √18975

Square root both sides.

c = sqrt(18975)

c = 137.74 cm

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).